# I am trying to send a request to OVH'S API, but when trying to do this i get an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ovh

I am trying to send a request to OVH's API using their python API wrapper to check if my IP address is in mitigation, when trying to do this I get the following error:

```
    result = client.get(f'/ip/{quote(ipblock)}/mitigation/{ipOnMitigation}', _need_auth=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ovh/client.py", line 347, in get
    return self.call('GET', _target, None, _need_auth)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ovh/client.py", line 442, in call
    raise ResourceNotFoundError(json_result.get('message'),
ovh.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: Got an invalid (or empty) URL
```

Here is my code

```
import json
import ovh 
from urllib.parse import quote


client = ovh.Client(
    endpoint='ovh-ca',               
    application_key='xxxxxxx',    
    application_secret='xxxxxxx',
    consumer_key='xxxxxxxxx'
)
ipblock = "xxxx/28"
ipOnMitigation = "xxx/32"

result = client.get(f'/ip/{quote(ipblock)}/mitigation/{ipOnMitigation}', _need_auth=False)
# Pretty print
print(json.dumps(result))
```

Comment: Do you have to quote the `ipOnMitigation` parameter as well?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the endpoint needs to look like a path (ie `/ovh-ca`)?

Edit: the exception indicates that something is wrong with the request. If it’s not the endpoint, it must be some other parameter your passing to the client (or not passing). I see you have a app key/secret pair. Does this endpoint require a consumer secret (to build a request signature for instance) also?

Comment: I have looked on api.ovh.com and i have passed all that needs to be passed.

Comment: @Dolphinmaybe I had a look at the api docs, and the only other things I can come up with are: the request shouldn’t set the _need_auth parameter, or the ids in the url are not valid for some reason (miscopied, or need to be escaped with a method like `urllib.parse.quote(ipblock, safe="")`